# Create a link in javascript to set value of public render parameter

Tags: javascript, websphere-portal

I'm trying to create a link within `javascript`, which when clicked, sets the value of a `public render parameter` within `WebSphere Portal`.
For some reason I see actual code in the generated `href` instead of value thats suppose to be passed in.

Heres how I create the link within `javascript` ..

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
var linkText = document.createTextNode('This is a link');
a.appendChild(linkText);
a.title = 'This is a link';
a.href = '[Plugin:RenderURL pr1.mode="set" pr1.type="public" pr1.key="sources" pr1.value=' + JSON.parse(http.responseText).uniqueID + ']';
```

This is what I see in the Firefox Inspector devtools ..

```
<a href="p0/IZ7_9O5CH940L8BE00AQSQ97LA0811=CZ6_9O5CH940LON880AAN4OSND00N6=MEsources!QCLQCAJSON.parse(http.responseText).uniqueIDQCAQCL==/#Z7_9O5CH940L8BE00AQSQ97LA0811" title="This is a link">This is a link</a>
```

I understand this is likely an escaping issue, but i've tried so many variations, how should I properly create the `href` for my link?

Comment: It seems you create your link after template/component rendered. I believe plugin tags generates something only on render phase and you cannot render something with plugin after your page loaded

Comment: Is this inside a JSP ?

Comment: I've created a `Content item`, which contains a `HTML component`. So when I drag this `Content item` onto a page the `HTML component` is rendered. The `HTML component` contains the `JavaScript` shown above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample for setting prp using a form, same idea as anchor above ..

```
// create form to set PRP
var f = document.createElement('form');
f.setAttribute('method', 'GET');
f.setAttribute('action', '[Plugin:RenderURL copyCurrentParams="true"]');

var filters = document.createElement('input');
filters.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
filters.setAttribute('name', 'sorting');
filters.value = 'This is my new value!';

var s = document.createElement('input'); //input element, Submit button
s.setAttribute('type', 'submit');
s.setAttribute('value', 'Set');

f.appendChild(filters);
f.appendChild(s);
document.body.appendChild(f);
f.submit();
```